# Why do I have to double click to actually do something?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

Code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(s=(26, 1), background_color='red', k='Input')],
    [sg.Button('White', s=(10, 1)), sg.Button('Black', s=(10, 1))],
]

window = sg.Window('test', layout=layout, margins=(1, 1))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    window.read()
    if event == 'White':
        window['Input'].update(background_color='white')
    if event == 'Black':
        window['Input'].update(background_color='black')
```

I made it so when you press a button the input field will change it's colour.

But why do I have to press the button twice to actually change it?

Comment: I always have a `print(event, values)` after every call to `window.read()`.  It makes finding dual reads possible, gives me events that I may not know are happening, etc.  It's a really effective debugging technique for these PSG programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event loop reads the event twice:

```py
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    window.read()
```

You only need it once.

Plus you should add an exit event.

Updated code:

```
layout = [
    [sg.Input(s=(26, 1), background_color='red', k='Input')],
    [sg.Button('White', s=(10, 1)), sg.Button('Black', s=(10, 1))],
]

window = sg.Window('test', layout=layout, margins=(1, 1))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == 'White':
        window['Input'].update(background_color='white')

    if event == 'Black':
        window['Input'].update(background_color='black')
```

Comment: Alright, thanks!
I found where in my code where I was reading the window twice and I fixed it.